# Rundeck variable from script steps to Inline Ansible Playbook

Tags: ansible, rundeck

I need to download a file from web URL and inflate into remote server, which does not have internet access.

1. Rundeck downloads the file into local path wget, then push the file
   to destination server using SSH
2. Rundeck to execute script on remote node to inflate the file copied using above step and 
   perform other housekeeping activity, (its a bash shell script)

I am with very little knowledge on using Rundeck.

**Step one**, I have got it done. File is downloaded to rundeck from URL and pushed to destination server.

```
    [ -d "/apps/support/dump/CNRLS2" ]  && rm -r "/apps/support/dump/CNRLS2"
    echo "Creating workspace folder"
    mkdir -p /apps/support/dump/CNRLS2
    cd /apps/support/dump/CNRLS2

   export ArtifactURL="https://artifact.dummy.dummyurl.com/artifactory/generic-release/XRSL/CNRLS/develop/113/RLAWESOME-1379.tar.gz"
    echo "Downloading Artifact at $ArtifactURL from Artifactory"
    wget -q $ArtifactURL --no-check-certificate 
    export packageName=$(echo "${ArtifactURL##*/}")
    echo $packageName
    scp -r /apps/support/dump/CNRLS2/*.* yurtdxx67a@11.28.293.88:/xmodules/fixes/migreq/
```

This pushed my package to remote server path `/xmodules/fixes/migreq/`

Now **Step Two**

I am running an inline ansible as the next step to perform the unpack on destination node. The ansible goes to destination node and invokes unpack.sh , **I am not able to pass the packageName value from previous step to inline ansible.**

```
---
  - hosts: "{{host_name}}"
    remote_user: "{{run_user}}"
    tasks:
      - name: Unpack the package
        shell: sh /home/yurtdxx67a/mig/unpack.sh "{{$packageName}}"
```

Any idea will be great help for me.

**Edit:12-Feb-2020**

In my case the variables to be substituted is within "ansible-extra-param"

```
  <command>
    <step-plugin type='com.batix.rundeck.plugins.AnsiblePlaybookInlineWorkflowStep'>
      <configuration>
        <entry key='ansible-become' value='false' />
        <entry key='ansible-disable-limit' value='false' />
        <entry key='ansible-extra-param' value='-i /tmp/workspace/CNRLS/hosts -e host_name=myhost -e run_user=${data.runUser} -e package_name=${data.packageName} --limit ${data.nodeIP} --ssh-extra-args=&apos;-o StrictHostKeyChecking=no&apos; ' />
        <entry key='ansible-playbook-inline' value='---&#10;  - hosts: "{{host_name}}"&#10;    remote_user: "{{run_user}}"&#10;    tasks:&#10;      - name: Check for connectivity&#10;        shell: sh /home/yurtdxx67a/mig/unpack.sh "{{package_name}}"  ' />
      </configuration>
    </step-plugin>
  </command>
```

I want to use these varaiables.

run_user=**${data.runUser}** -e package_name=$**{data.packageName}** --limit $**{data.nodeIP}**

these variable has value. when I display
      
        echo ${data.packageName} ; echo ${data.runUser} ; echo ${data.nodeIP} ;

I am not sure how to use these variable as part of "ansible-extra-param' argument

Thank you again

Thank you. 
Dwija

Answer (score 0):

You can "extract" values from your script output using [data passing](https://youtu.be/ao2SvpspWl4?t=175) feature, you'll store it on data variables and then send it to your ansible using `${data.MYDATA}` format.

I  leave a very basic example that works:

```xml
<joblist>
  <job>
    <defaultTab>nodes</defaultTab>
    <description></description>
    <dispatch>
      <excludePrecedence>true</excludePrecedence>
      <keepgoing>false</keepgoing>
      <rankOrder>ascending</rankOrder>
      <successOnEmptyNodeFilter>false</successOnEmptyNodeFilter>
      <threadcount>1</threadcount>
    </dispatch>
    <executionEnabled>true</executionEnabled>
    <id>c858b2a9-8328-4bdb-8955-0394b238cfbc</id>
    <loglevel>INFO</loglevel>
    <name>ExampleAnsible</name>
    <nodeFilterEditable>false</nodeFilterEditable>
    <nodefilters>
      <filter>192.168.33.2.*</filter>
    </nodefilters>
    <nodesSelectedByDefault>true</nodesSelectedByDefault>
    <scheduleEnabled>true</scheduleEnabled>
    <sequence keepgoing='false' strategy='node-first'>
      <command>
        <plugins>
          <LogFilter type='key-value-data'>
            <config>
              <logData>true</logData>
              <regex>^(MYSTRING)\s*=\s*(.+)$</regex>
            </config>
          </LogFilter>
        </plugins>
        <script><![CDATA[# your script
echo "MYSTRING=World"]]></script>
        <scriptargs />
      </command>
      <command>
        <node-step-plugin type='com.batix.rundeck.plugins.AnsiblePlaybookInlineWorkflowNodeStep'>
          <configuration>
            <entry key='ansible-become' value='false' />
            <entry key='ansible-playbook-inline' value='---&#10;- name: hello-world&#10;  hosts: all&#10;  tasks:&#10;    - name: hello-world&#10;      copy:&#10;        content: hello ${data.MYSTRING}&#10;        dest: /home/vagrant/testfile.txt' />
            <entry key='ansible-ssh-passphrase-option' value='option.password' />
            <entry key='ansible-ssh-use-agent' value='false' />
          </configuration>
        </node-step-plugin>
      </command>
    </sequence>
    <uuid>c858b2a9-8328-4bdb-8955-0394b238cfbc</uuid>
  </job>
</joblist>
```