# Rundeck controlling Proxmox through REST API

Tags: ansible, rundeck, proxmox

I'm completely new to Rundeck, which I installed with Docker. My goal is to control a Proxmox cluster with its APIs. How can I do that? Maybe with Ansible?
Do you have pointers for me?

Thanks in advance

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ansible isn't necessary for that. You can create a [workflow](https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/manual/job-workflows.html#job-workflows) with [HTTP Workflow step](https://github.com/rundeck-plugins/http-step) plugin to send the [API](https://pve.proxmox.com/wiki/Proxmox_VE_API) request to your Proxmox host ([download](https://github.com/rundeck-plugins/http-step/releases/download/1.0.12/http-step-1.0.12.jar) the jar file from here and [put it on the libext directory](https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/administration/configuration/plugins/installing.html#installing-plugins) or use the plugin manager to install it [ Gear icon > Plugins > Find Plugins > Search "HTTP Workflow Step" and click on "Install" button ], you don't need to restart the instance).

Alternatively, you can create a workflow with a [script-step](https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/manual/node-steps/builtin.html#script-step) that the Proxmox API call using [cURL](https://curl.haxx.se/) directly. Also, you can pass [options](https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/manual/job-options.html#job-options) dynamically to your script step using `@option.myoption@` syntax (for example, pass the actions from an options list).

I leave a job definition example with both ways to do this (using [httpbin.org](https://httpbin.org/) service and passing a couple of options to both steps).

```xml
<joblist>
  <job>
    <context>
      <options preserveOrder='true'>
        <option name='action' value='anything' />
        <option name='host' value='httpbin.org' />
      </options>
    </context>
    <defaultTab>nodes</defaultTab>
    <description></description>
    <executionEnabled>true</executionEnabled>
    <id>da60f0f8-d3d1-4f6d-b01e-704e00fa2ae8</id>
    <loglevel>INFO</loglevel>
    <name>APICallExample</name>
    <nodeFilterEditable>false</nodeFilterEditable>
    <plugins />
    <scheduleEnabled>true</scheduleEnabled>
    <sequence keepgoing='false' strategy='node-first'>
      <command>
        <description>Example using http workflow step plugin</description>
        <step-plugin type='edu.ohio.ais.rundeck.HttpWorkflowStepPlugin'>
          <configuration>
            <entry key='authentication' value='None' />
            <entry key='checkResponseCode' value='true' />
            <entry key='headers' value='{"Accept": "application/json"}' />
            <entry key='method' value='POST' />
            <entry key='printResponse' value='true' />
            <entry key='printResponseToFile' value='false' />
            <entry key='proxySettings' value='false' />
            <entry key='remoteUrl' value='https://${option.host}/${option.action}' />
            <entry key='responseCode' value='200' />
            <entry key='sslVerify' value='false' />
            <entry key='timeout' value='30000' />
          </configuration>
        </step-plugin>
      </command>
      <command>
        <description>Example using script-step</description>
        <fileExtension>.sh</fileExtension>
        <script><![CDATA[curl -X POST "https://@option.host@/@option.action@" -H  "accept: application/json"]]></script>
        <scriptargs />
        <scriptinterpreter>/bin/bash</scriptinterpreter>
      </command>
    </sequence>
    <uuid>da60f0f8-d3d1-4f6d-b01e-704e00fa2ae8</uuid>
  </job>
</joblist>
```

Comment: Any time Greg :-)

Comment: Which one do you prefer? and how do you handle return values like the token given by the first call and used by the following calls?

Comment: Hi Greg, I prefer the "script step" option, you can catch any value and pass it using data-passing feature like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59754851/10426011 more info here: https://www.rundeck.com/blog/output-processing-data-passing-preview

Comment: Thanks. I've seen the videos but I cannot figure out how to fetch values which not in "key=value" format (such as plain values or JSON)...

Comment: Using regex is a good way, take a look at this tool to create and test your regexs: https://www.freeformatter.com/java-regex-tester.html