# Rundeck to run AWS Lambda function

Tags: aws-lambda, rundeck

Does anyone have any information on how to run AWS lambda scripts from rundeck? I was looking into doing this to have a central place that certain uses can log into run deck and run the scripts that are relevant to them, as not everyone has aws access.

I found this: https://www.slideshare.net/tetutaro/lambda-and-rundeck-58884982

But I was hoping there might be something more official somewhere and in English :)

Answer (score 1):

A good way to integrate with Lambda is to use [AWS CLI](https://aws.amazon.com/cli/) on the Rundeck server and call functions using script step or command step on your workflow. Take a look at [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/gettingstarted-awscli.html).

Also, and similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64536684/10426011) answer, another good way to interact with Lamda is to access it using [API](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/API_Operations.html) (you have two options: using [HTTP Workflow Step](https://github.com/rundeck-plugins/http-step) plugin or via [script step](https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/manual/node-steps/builtin.html#script-step) on your [workflow](https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/manual/job-workflows.html#job-workflows)).

Finally, maybe is a good opportunity to develop some [custom plugin](https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/developer/01-plugin-development.html) focused on AWS Lambda.